# Meaning of "we're not out to get anybody"

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of *We're not out to get anybody*? This is a message from a teacher to the student.

Comment: I just edited the main message to add the context.

Comment: A standard reference will answer this question. Google [ define "out to get" ] returns a link to a reputable dictionary definition as the first result and reports the definition in the search result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a teacher says to a group of students

> We are not out to get anybody

he probably means

> We are not here to punish anyone.

Answer (score 4):

It's similar to using these expressions:

> *We're not on a witch hunt*...
>
> *We don't have a hidden agenda*...
>
> *We're not targeting anyone*...
>
> *We're just trying to determine the root of the problem*...